# How to clear MUI Autocomplete to initial state

Tags: material-ui, autocomplete, react-hook-form

I would like to reset/clear my MUI Autocomplete component.
I have two of them with model like `{ label: string, value: string }` and if first will change its value then I would like to clear the second one since second will get options by selected value in first one.

Moreover - I am using `react-hook-form` with `setValue`. I use as value in this method `{ label: '', value: '' }` but it causes warning that in my new sort of options there is no such option to select (this is minor issue I think) but it does not reset second Autocomplete input but partially. I still see `X` to clear value. I used `null` as value in `setValue` but it does not cleat input as well.

What I want to achieve is - selecting some option on first input I would like to reset second input like clicking on `X` does. Is it possible ?

Cheers!

Comment: You can use `react-hook-form`'s `reset` function that allows you to reset any field to its initial value, you can use it as: `reset(fieldName)`

Comment: u can use `watch` from react hook form to watch the changes in the first autocomplete and if it's value is '' u can use reset to reset the second autocomplete. Leave a comment if this works.

Comment: Actually it is not about reset the field in the form library itself but reset it to the value that Autocomplete will treat as `nothing` like after clicking `X` on Autocomplete when option is chosen. I have all logic done but I do not get how to completely reset the Autocomplete. As I said I have option model like this `{ label: 'display name', value: '1'}`. It is passed to Autocomplete as array of options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what caused the issue I describe above. It was because Autocomplete in my codebase was declared with `clearOnBlur={false}` props. It prevented to clear value of my Autocomplete when I was doing `setValue(autocompleteFieldName, null)` via `react-hook-form`. I hope it helps someone with the same strange issue since I was not interacting with input at all to invoke `onBlur` event. Cheers!